# Are the invertible matrices which are used to find the SNF always part of the ideal principle domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

Let's say SNF = T*A*T^-1.
Do T and T inverse always only have elements part of the domain?

For example, if we have an integer matrix, will T and T inverse only have integer values (not rational numbers). That would also be equivalent to T having a determinant of one with integer values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can always choose $T$ in a way that $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are both integral. But if you are given a rational $T$ such that $TAT^{-1}$ is the Smith normal form, it is possible for $T$ or $T^{-1}$ to not be integral.